# How to wait for DOM to load in protractor tests

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am hitting the url in browser by "browser.get(url)" and then I am expecting something to be present on the screen. But My test cases are failing because it is taking some time to load the page and test cases are executed before the page loads. So is there a way where I can wait for DOM to load and then the rest of the test cases are executed. I do not want to put sleep as the time to load the page is not consistent and it is unnecessary delay in executing the tests.

I am looking for some solution where we can wait for DOM to load and then we go to next tests to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by waiting for some specific element to be present on the screen and then perform next activity: here is the code, how I am waiting for the element:

```
browser.wait(function(){
    return browser.driver.isElementPresent(by.id(elementId));
},30000);
```

So, if you have doubt that execution can happen before the element is present on the screen, then just wait for some element to be present on the screen and then perform next activity.

Hope this will help other, who will face same kind of issues.

Comment: Failed: browser.driver.isElementPresent is not a function

Answer (score -1):

You can put a timeout for the script in your config

```
jasmineNodeOpts: {defaultTimeoutInterval: 70000}
```

This will wait AT MAX for specified time.

Comment: putting time out will not wait for all the elements to load, we might get timeout errors more often than page to load